# How do you listen for changes in the length of the input array

Tags: angular, immutability

I made a `MenuComponent` component and I want to sense that `list` length has changed and do something like make a request.

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

type List = {username:string}[]

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.component.scss']
})
export class MenuComponent {
  @Input() list:List = []
  @Output() listChange = new EventEmitter<List>()
}
```

When I call the `add` method of the `AppComponent` component, `MenuComponent` doesn't know.

How do you let `MenuComponent` know?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <button (click)="add()">button</button>
  <app-menu [(list)]="list"></app-menu>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  list = [
    { username: "foo" }
  ]

  add() {
    this.list.push({ username: "bar" })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't, that's why immutability exists.

When mutating your data, you should always create a new array instead of just pushing to it.